# tinyMCE and jquery-ui conflict

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tinymce

I'm using tinyMCE majorVersion:"3",minorVersion:"4.4",releaseDate:"2011-08-04"
and it works fine, until I register jquery-ui script. After that, on first hover of any tinyMCE toolbar icons, jquery start creating

```
<div id="ui-tooltip-0" class="ui-tooltip ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-widget-content" role="tooltip">
```

divs on my page. After that first hover, it create this div on hover to any html object and throws `TypeError: "".split is not a function`

Comment: I have the same issue, have you found anything on the topic through the years ? :D

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried playing with the order in which the scripts are being loaded? Have you also tried calling `jQuery.noConflict()`

Comment: it is not jQuery that's the problem. Problem is that I'm using yii bootstrap, which on initialization adds popover and tooltip which gets conflicted with tinyMCE tooltip. In new bootsrtap version tooltip is attached on jQuery('body'), so I removed it from initialization

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle so we can work on this?... sounds like a namespace problem.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to load jQuery plugins (e.g. jquery-ui.js & jquery-tinymce.js) is to add them after jquery-x.x.x.js (where the basic jQuery prototype is defined).

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js">//Basic jquery prototype</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js">//jquery extensions (plugins)</script>
```

TinyMCE has its own basic prototype and doesn't interfere with jQuery. While the plugin (jquery-tinymce.js) must not be included before jQuery, the tinyMCE prototype (tinymce.js) can be included either before or after.

I had a similar issue for several hours until I discovered that I unintentionally reloaded jQuery with new content from a file - which contained a new *<script src="...jquery-x.x.x.js"></script>* - into my existing page with [$.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/). If you've made sure your  tags come in the right order and any plugin still seems to fail, you should look for subsequent inclutions with [$.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/), [$.getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) ore similar.